# Kindless Queries in App Engine Go

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

In Python it's

```
q = db.Query()
q.ancestor(ancestor_key)
```

I tried:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("")
q.Ancestor(ancestor_key)
```

I get the error "datastore: empty kind" when running GetAll

I also tried:

```
q := &datastore.Query{}
q.Ancestor(ancestor_key)
```

I get the error "datastore: empty query kind"

Thanks in advance for any help with this matter.

Comment: I don't think the Python kindless ancestor query is supported in Go. For a moment there I thought you could use the ancestor key's Kind() method, then I had some more coffee and came to my senses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich Churcher's comment seems to be right, at least at this point in time.

> I don't think the Python kindless ancestor query is supported in Go.
>   For a moment there I thought you could use the ancestor key's Kind()
>   method, then I had some more coffee and came to my senses.

Answer (score 2):

> [func NewQuery](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#NewQuery)
>
> func NewQuery(kind string) *Query
>
> NewQuery creates a new Query for a specific entity kind. The kind must
>   be non-empty.

In your code,

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("")
```

the kind is empty.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of it being a "Kindless" query. I understand what you mean though; I was just trying to show that I actually _tried_ before posting here. I thought that was the way it's done on SO.

Answer (score 0):

GetAll doesn't seem to work, but you can do kindless queries.

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
q := datastore.NewQuery("")
for it := q.Run(ctx); ; {
  key, err := t.Next(nil)
  if err == datastore.Done {
    break
  }
  if err != nil {
    break
  }
  fmt.Printf("%v\n", key)
}
```